# Registering local folders on ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

We have all our geodatabases stored on a dedicated ArcGIS server in a folder D:\GeoData. This folder is shared as \\GISSERVER\GeoData. Any users working from their work stations have to reference this UNC path, however the server can reference this as local path D:\GeoData

My question is, should the UNC path always be used, and local path NEVER used, even if publishing from the server? I am proposing that the data be moved to a different server so that there is never any ambiguity, i.e. everyone uses the same path, period.

Presently, we have 2x registered folders for the same data source (folder). One is Local and one is UNC. It doesn't make sense to me. We never copy data to the server when publishing, always keeping a single source.

Comment: My 2 cents worth.. Using a UNC fully qualified path has no detriment as it goes through the loopback interface if it's on the local computer. If you make it a static path d:\GeoData then you have to ensure if you move servers you also move d:\GeoData which will cause problems with users calling \\server\GeoData who now have to use \\newserver\geodata. Installing a new computer and recycling name is a right pain but can be done, if you're prepared to go through that by all means use the local path.

Comment: OK, so all MXDs should reference the UNC path, regardless of whether they are used on the server or not? This means, never use the local path. It also means I only have to register one folder. 
PS. I have deliberately avoided talking about mapped drives :)

Comment: Mapped drives have their uses. I would say that the UNC path would be preferred but you have to keep in mind that when you upgrade that server you will need to recycle the name. In this case a mapped drive (let's say X:) is mapped to \\server\Data and then you upgrade, just change the mapping of X: to \\newserver\data and you're done! Some will say avoid using a local path as it poses a security risk; it's possible that external users can glean that information from your service... not that they can do much with it, but better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Here's a post that might explain replacing a server and recycling the name http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/75097-replace-an-old-file-server-with-a-new-file-server-using-the-same-ip-same-name-same-shares though it might be as simple as revoking the lease on the DNS, renaming the old server and giving the new server the old name *provided that the GISSERVER isn't your DNS* then it gets really sticky!